# Jest spyOn-function returns "'_isMockFunction' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme, jestjs

I'm trying to test a React-Component.

I call a function during `componentDidMount`and want to test that it is called.

Unfortunately I get an error when I want to run the test:

`Cannot read property '_isMockFunction' of undefined`

I tried to reproduce a minimal example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/xoy59yr34z

Any hints as to why this error occurs would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your test with Component.prototype:

```
  const buildActionsColumn = jest.spyOn(
    FieldAutoComplete.prototype,
    "buildActionsColumn"
  );
```

Comment: And if you rename your FieldAutoComplete.jsx to FieldAutoComplete.js ?